# Pivoting longer twice and simultaneously

Tags: r, pivot

How can we achieve this goal without generating 2 DFs and then merging them?

In the following code, the new “covariate” variable (after the last pipe) is added in the following rows.

```
dat_long_test <- dat  %>%
  pivot_longer(
    c( glucose_mmol, trig_mmol, col_total_mmol),
    names_to = "outcomes_long", values_to = "outcomes_long_values")%>%
  pivot_longer(
    c( glucose_mmol_cov, trig_mmol_cov, col_total_mmol_cov),
    names_to = "covariates_long", values_to = "covariates_long_values")
```

But I wish it would be a new column, next to “outcomes”, so that the new DF would have three columns ("outcomes_names" | “outcomes_values” | “covariate_values”), with paired observations.

DF below

```
    dat <- structure(list(ID = c("HF_01", "HF_01", "HF_02", "HF_02", "HF_03", 
"HF_03", "HF_04", "HF_04"), time = c("3month", "4month", "3month", 
"4month", "3month", "4month", "3month", "4month"), group = c("CONTROL", 
"CONTROL", "INT", "INT", "CONTROL", "CONTROL", "INT", 
"INT"), glucose_mmol = c(2.37912, 2.30154, 2.56014, 2.68944, 
2.37912, NA, 2.48256, 2.37912), trig_mmol = c(1.70676, 1.75848, 
1.91364, 2.0688, 4.68066, NA, 1.78434, 1.5516), col_total_mmol = c(4.47378, 
5.0427, 4.60308, 4.3962, 6.38742, NA, 2.81874, 2.79288), glucose_mmol_cov = c(2.4567, 
2.4567, 2.53428, 2.53428, 2.56014, 2.56014, 2.40498, 2.40498), 
    trig_mmol_cov = c(2.74116, 2.74116, 1.8102, 1.8102, 5.87022, 
    5.87022, 3.05148, 3.05148), col_total_mmol_cov = c(4.75824, 
    4.75824, 3.69798, 3.69798, 6.18054, 6.18054, 3.07734, 3.07734
    )), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a consistent suffix to the non-covariate columns, then `pivot_longer()` with `names_pattern` and the `".value"` sentinel:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  rename_with(
    \(x) paste0(x, "_val"),
    !ends_with("_cov")
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = c("variable", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "(.+)_(\\w+$)"
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 24 × 3
   variable         val   cov
   <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
 1 glucose_mmol    2.38  2.46
 2 trig_mmol       1.71  2.74
 3 col_total_mmol  4.47  4.76
 4 glucose_mmol    2.30  2.46
 5 trig_mmol       1.76  2.74
 6 col_total_mmol  5.04  4.76
 7 glucose_mmol    2.56  2.53
 8 trig_mmol       1.91  1.81
 9 col_total_mmol  4.60  3.70
10 glucose_mmol    2.69  2.53
# ℹ 14 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you. But any other alternative and by specificying the columns? This was a simple case - in reality I may wish to use other variables as ID, GROUP, TIME in dat. This solution might not be the best for such cases?

Comment: You can specify the columns by replacing `!ends_with("_cov")` with `c(glucose_mmol, trig_mmol, col_total_mmol)`, and `everything()` with `glucose_mmol_val:col_total_mmol_cov` (if the variables are all next to another another) or `c(se_mmol_val, trig_mmol_val, col_total_mmol_val, glucose_mmol_cov, trig_mmol_cov, col_total_mmol_cov)` (if not). Refer to the [tidyselect helpers](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html). If that doesn’t answer your question, please edit your post to include more representative sample data.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the post with more variables. If I understood well your instructions, the last code did not worked. dat_reprex2 <- dat_reprex %>%
  rename_with(
    \(x) paste0(x, "_val"),
    c(glucose_mmol, trig_mmol, col_total_mmol)
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    c(glucose_mmol_cov, trig_mmol_cov, col_total_mmol_cov),
    names_to = c("variable", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "(.+)_(\\w+$)"
  )

Comment: You need to also the `_val` variables in `pivot_longer()`, as in my previous comment. You could also use `glucose_mmol_val:col_total_mmol_cov`.